# Angular routerLink routes properly but route.navigate in component routes to default path

Tags: angular-routing

The Basic Sample is created 
The Source Code is   [Uploaded Here](https://github.com/kishanhari54/basic)
and   [Deployed Here](https://kishanhari54.github.io/basic)

- A route is set with path :"products"
- In app.template.html using routerLink directive a route is set ->
  when "Products" gets clicked --> The route "products" is opened as
  expected, but activating the same route through code
  (`this.route.navigate(['/products']`) in "app.component.ts" navigates
  to this 'home'.

This is basic but weird, **where have I gone wrong** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's getting redirected on your `app.component.html` on line 19:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="navigateBack()"> Products(navigated in Component)</a>
```

This tag has `href="#"` so the page is getting routed to your root because your `app-routing.module.ts` file is redirecting to home.

```
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

So, remove `href="#"` with `[routerLink]="[]"` and it should resolve the issue.